# XSLT Create copies of Parent Node from Child Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with XSLT and I have a requirement that I'm not sure how to proceed with.

I've included images below as the scenario is a bit difficult to explain.

**Before**: There is 1 tree node and there are 2 leaf nodes in each of the  nodes.

**After**: There are 2 tree nodes. The 1st tree holds the first leaf nodes under leaves and the 2nd tree holds the second leaf nodes under leaves.

[Before XML Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO3ep.png)

[After XML Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0glzr.png)

I'm unsure if I should go outwards in, tree -> leaf or inwards out, leaf -> tree in my template matching..

Thank you for any help!

Update:

**Before XML as Text**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tree uId="0">
  <branches uId="1">
    <branch uId="2">
      <branchId uId="3">0988890098887656</branchId>
      <number uId="4">7</number>
      <leaves uId="5">
        <leaf uId="6">
          <name uId="7">Leaf 1</name>
        </leaf>
        <leaf uId="8">
          <name uId="9">Leaf 2</name>
        </leaf>
      </leaves>
      <bugs uId="10">10</bugs>
    </branch>
    <branch uId="11">
      <branchId uId="12">66677755564446</branchId>
      <number uId="13" />
      <leaves uId="14">
        <leaf uId="15">
          <name uId="16">Leaf 1</name>
        </leaf>
        <leaf uId="17">
          <name uId="18">Leaf 2</name>
        </leaf>
      </leaves>
      <bugs uId="19" />
    </branch>
  </branches>
  <title uId="20">Great Tree</title>
</tree>
```

**After XML as Text:**

```
<tree uId="0">
  <branches uId="1">
    <branch uId="2">
      <branchId uId="3">0988890098887656</branchId>
      <number uId="4">7</number>
      <leaves uId="5">
        <leaf uId="6">
          <name uId="7">Leaf 1</name>
        </leaf>
      </leaves>
      <bugs uId="10">10</bugs>
    </branch>
    <branch uId="11">
      <branchId uId="12">66677755564446</branchId>
      <number uId="13" />
      <leaves uId="14">
        <leaf uId="15">
          <name uId="16">Leaf 1</name>
        </leaf>
      </leaves>
      <bugs uId="19" />
    </branch>
  </branches>
  <title uId="20">Great Tree</title>
</tree>
<tree>
  <branches>
    <branch>
      <branchId>0988890098887656</branchId>
      <number>7</number>
      <leaves>
        <leaf uId="8">
          <name uId="9">Leaf 2</name>
        </leaf>
      </leaves>
      <bugs>10</bugs>
    </branch>
    <branch>
      <branchId>66677755564446</branchId>
      <number/>
      <leaves>
        <leaf uId="17">
          <name uId="18">Leaf 2</name>
        </leaf>
      </leaves>
      <bugs />
    </branch>
  </branches>
  <title>Great Tree</title>
</tree>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="tree">
        <xsl:variable name="copies">
            <xsl:call-template name="getTreeCopies" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($copies)/*"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getTreeCopies">
        <xsl:variable name="countOfLeaf" select="count((.//leaves)[1]/leaf)" />
        <xsl:call-template name="getTreeCopy">
            <xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="$countOfLeaf" />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getTreeCopy">
        <xsl:param name="i" />
        <xsl:param name="count" />

        <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:call-template name="getTreeCopy" >
                <xsl:with-param name="i">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XSLT so far copies the tree node (number of leaf nodes in leaves node per branch) times. The next step would be to remove leaf at position 1 from tree 1 and leaf at position 2 from tree 2... etc and then remove the uid attributes from any copies of the original tree.

Comment: Can you include your XML in the question as text, rather than images, please. It would also help to include any XSLT you have currently tried. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my question with the xmls and my current approach and xslt. Please let me know if you think I'm going in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan - Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way would be to:

- Create a key of `leaf`'s based on their position.
- Process the first `leaf` for each key. ([Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html))
- The first leaf in a key triggers processing of the ancestor tree (and its descendants).
- A list of generated ID's for all of the `leaf`'s in the key are passed as a parameter. (Since XSLT 1.0 doesn't support tunneling, it will need to be passed in each apply-templates call.)
- When the `leaves` element is processed, only `leaf` elements with a matching generated ID are processed.
- The use of `mode`'s can control whether or not attributes are processed.

Example (also demonstrated here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2a)...

**XML Input**

```
<tree uId="0">
    <branches uId="1">
        <branch uId="2">
            <branchId uId="3">0988890098887656</branchId>
            <number uId="4">7</number>
            <leaves uId="5">
                <leaf uId="6">
                    <name uId="7">Leaf 1</name>
                </leaf>
                <leaf uId="8">
                    <name uId="9">Leaf 2</name>
                </leaf>
            </leaves>
            <bugs uId="10">10</bugs>
        </branch>
        <branch uId="11">
            <branchId uId="12">66677755564446</branchId>
            <number uId="13" />
            <leaves uId="14">
                <leaf uId="15">
                    <name uId="16">Leaf 1</name>
                </leaf>
                <leaf uId="17">
                    <name uId="18">Leaf 2</name>
                </leaf>
            </leaves>
            <bugs uId="19" />
        </branch>
    </branches>
    <title uId="20">Great Tree</title>
</tree>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="leaves" match="leaf" use="count(preceding-sibling::leaf) + 1"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//leaf[count(.|key('leaves',count(preceding-sibling::leaf) + 1)[1])=1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="full">
    <xsl:param name="leafId"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="full">
        <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="$leafId"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="partial">
    <xsl:param name="leafId"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="partial">
        <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="$leafId"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="leaves" mode="full">
    <xsl:param name="leafId"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|leaf[contains($leafId,concat('|',generate-id()))]" mode="full"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="leaves" mode="partial">
    <xsl:param name="leafId"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="leaf[contains($leafId,concat('|',generate-id()))]" mode="full"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="leaf">
    <xsl:variable name="leafId">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('leaves',count(preceding-sibling::leaf)+1)">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('|',generate-id())"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::tree" mode="full">
          <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="$leafId"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::tree" mode="partial">
          <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="$leafId"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>        
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<tree uId="0">
   <branches uId="1">
      <branch uId="2">
         <branchId uId="3">0988890098887656</branchId>
         <number uId="4">7</number>
         <leaves uId="5">
            <leaf uId="6">
               <name uId="7">Leaf 1</name>
            </leaf>
         </leaves>
         <bugs uId="10">10</bugs>
      </branch>
      <branch uId="11">
         <branchId uId="12">66677755564446</branchId>
         <number uId="13"/>
         <leaves uId="14">
            <leaf uId="15">
               <name uId="16">Leaf 1</name>
            </leaf>
         </leaves>
         <bugs uId="19"/>
      </branch>
   </branches>
   <title uId="20">Great Tree</title>
</tree>
<tree>
   <branches>
      <branch>
         <branchId>0988890098887656</branchId>
         <number>7</number>
         <leaves>
            <leaf uId="8">
               <name uId="9">Leaf 2</name>
            </leaf>
         </leaves>
         <bugs>10</bugs>
      </branch>
      <branch>
         <branchId>66677755564446</branchId>
         <number/>
         <leaves>
            <leaf uId="17">
               <name uId="18">Leaf 2</name>
            </leaf>
         </leaves>
         <bugs/>
      </branch>
   </branches>
   <title>Great Tree</title>
</tree>
```